# Compiler Errors(undeclared identifier/conflicting types/previous declaration) for Complicated Trace

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this but am getting some errors (listed below code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int num;
    char *word;
    struct foo *ptr;
};

void func2(struct foo *);
void func3(struct foo);

int main() {
    a.num = 100;
    a.word = "secondword";
    func2(&a);
    printf("2 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);

    a.ptr = &a;
    a.num = 50;
    a.word = "mylastword";
    func3(&a);
    printf("4 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);
}

void func2(struct foo *a) {
    while (*(a->word) != '\0') {
        putchar(*(a->word));
        a->word++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    if (a->num % 10 != 0) {
        a->num *= 2;
    }
    a->word--;
    printf("num is %d\n", (*a).num);
}

void func3(struct foo *a) {
    if ((*a).num == a->ptr->num) {
        (*a).num = (*((*a).ptr)).num + 1;
    } else {
        a->num = 200; 
    }
    a->word = "wordsix";
    a->ptr->word = "wordseven";
    printf("7th is %d %s\n", (*a).num, (*((*a).ptr)).word);
```

Compiled Output:
    Errors w/ lines 16:
    -each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    - 'a' undeclared

```
Lines 42:
-conflicting types for ‘func3’
-previous declaration of ‘func3’ was here)
```

Comment: Are we supposed to count lines here??? Put the error as a comment on the corresponding line!

Comment: Have you bothered reading your code before posting. Those 2 `func3()`s are clearly different!

Comment: `void func3(struct foo);` --> `void func3(struct foo*);`, put `struct foo a;` after `int main() {`.

Comment: You should also mention that this is a debugging homework(assignment).

Answer (score 1):

`func3` is defined as

```
void func3(struct foo *a)
```

but it is been previously declared as

```
void func3(struct foo);
```

Taking a structure by value and a pointer to a structure are 2 very different things. You forgot to type the `*` before the `)`.

Note that `(*a).num` is exactly equivalent to `a->num` but much less readable.  Avoid cluttering your code with this kind of contorted syntax.